# Outlook like autocomplete textbox

Tags: wpf, autocomplete

Hi I'm new to WPF and I'm trying to develop a textbox functions same as the "send to" text box in outlook. Currently I have refered to these posts [post1](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox) and [post2](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/). I'm having trouble with combining all these together. Have anyone solve this problem? Or Pls show me some example implementations of Autocomplete textbox in WPF.

Answer (score 0):

have you tried this..
[AutoComplete Text Box](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/44920/A-Reusable-WPF-Autocomplete-TextBox)

Comment: Yap, Currently trying on using that :), but even in that solution have to improve the look and feel alot

Answer (score 0):

http://blog.pixelingene.com/2010/10/tokenizing-control-convert-text-to-tokens/ - Have a look at this

Answer (score 0):

Another good example of a Autocompletetextbox can be found at
http://kiwiingenuity.net.nz/post/A-WPF-Text-Box-Autocomplete-Extender-Using-Reactive-Extensions